# How to setup http-proxy-middleware using same endpoint for different api url | React | Axios

Tags: reactjs, http-proxy-middleware

I am trying to setup http-proxy-middleware for multiple API URLs with same end point, which is not working.

setupProxy.php

```
const proxy =require("http-proxy-middleware");

module.exports = function(app)
{
  app.use(proxy("rest/V1/orders",{target:"http://example.net/",changeOrigin:true}));
  app.use(proxy("rest/V1/orders",{target:"http://example.org/",changeOrigin:true}));
  app.use(proxy("rest/V1/orders",{target:"http://example.com/",changeOrigin:true}));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use [this package](https://github.com/chimurai/http-proxy-middleware#readme) for https-proxy-middleware

For setup Create `setupProxy.js` under `src` directory

Ref the doc for sample code

Comment: Hi iam using https-proxy-middleware package only My issue is for multiple API URLs with same endpoint, not working  as expected please suggest, PFA code in setupProxy.php

Comment: Multiple API URLs with same endpoints means `https://ex.com/test` and `https://ex1.com/test` like these...

As I can't write an entier code in a comment I could edit my answer based on your need

Comment: Multiple API URLs with same endpoints means https://ex.com/test and https://ex1.com/test like these. correct, I need   the same. please suggest on this.

Comment: If you are fetching like this who do you need a proxy in the first place you could directly call the endpoints from the client right